# JavaScript within Python in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to call on a JavaScript function within my Python code. How should I do that? Here, I want to parse my url to get the query and check whether it is the same as name of a greeting in my datastore.

```
    {% for greeting in greetings %}
    {% if greeting.person %}
    <tr><th>{{ greeting.person.email }}
      {% if %}getQueryVariable() {%== greeting.name %}
        <th>{{greeting.name}}</th>
        <th>{{greeting.place}}</th>
        <th>{{greeting.time}}</th>
        <th>{{greeting.rec}}</th>
        <th>{{greeting.other}}</th>
      {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}</tr>
<script>
  function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split('=');
      if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
          return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
      }
  }
  console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you using Flask or Django?

Comment: @KevinGuan I'm using webapp2.